# Failed to Connect to database: Underlying database error occured

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, personal-geodatabase

I'm trying to connect to a personal database in ArcGIS 10.2 that contains work that I've spent the last two weeks working on but I am now receiving an error:

*Failed to connect to database. An underlying database error occurred. Unrecognized database format 'F:\streets.mdb'.*

Operating system: Windows 7, Database type: personal, Parent Directory: Networked

I'm really hoping there is a solution to this problem. Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

*EDIT*
Just noticed there is an associated LDB file that is currently in the folder with the database. If I understand correctly an LDB file is some sort of lock that should disappear once you have closed the file you are working with. Could this be the source of the issue?

Comment: Looks like your trying to connect to a person geodatabase (.mdb) You state your are working in a file geodatabase (.fgb)

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Are you using a personal geodatabase (.mdb file) or file geodatabase (.gdb directory)? Is the parent directory local or networked?  How frequent are your backups?  Please update the question (vice answering in comments).

Comment: You are right. I meant personal geodatabase.

Comment: I would almost bet that you recently upgraded to a x64 office. if so, the only solution I have found. Which I don't really like that much. but a fix is a affix as long as it doesn't break something else. I downloaded AccessDatabaseEngine.exe and ran it. You might think you would want the x64 version but alas it doesn't fix the problem. This is also true when you try to open an excel file

Comment: I would delete the ldb file.